# HTML5 Canvas Scale position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im trying out canvas for the first time and have a few questions about scaling.

After i scale the canvas up (half) i want to set the current position. The scale always sets the canvas to pos 0,0 (top-left).

If anyone knows how i could change the position while scaling please leave a answer!

Example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLG4v.png original.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gHno.png needed result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you have shown in the images.

```
// ctx is the canvas 2d context
// img is the image
function showImageScaled(img,scale,x,y){
    // scale is how big you want it. 
    // x and y are where in the image you want the top left to be
    ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,0,0);
    ctx.drawImage(img,-x,-y); // move the image
}
```

So to view the top corner scaled up to twice

```
showImageScaled(img,2,0,0);
```

To show the centre in the top left and the image scaled 4 times

```
showImageScaled(img,4,img.width/2,img.height/2);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example:

```js
    const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const canvasArea = canvas.width * 2 + canvas.height * 2;
    const radius = canvasArea * 0.1;
    const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    const color = 'blue';

    function drawCircle(context, scale, centerX, centerY, radius, color){
          context.save()
          context.beginPath();
          context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        context.scale(scale,scale);
          context.translate(-centerX,-centerY);
          context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fill();    
        context.restore()
    }

    function change(el) {
      canvas.width = canvas.width;
      canvas.height = canvas.height;

        const scale = el.value / el.max;

        drawCircle(ctx, scale, centerX, centerY, radius, color);
    }

    change(document.getElementById('rangeInput'));
```

```html
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
    <br>
    
    <input id='rangeInput' type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" oninput='change(this)' onchange='change(this)' style="width:200px">
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the solution given by [Blindman67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877726/blindman67)

You can use this precision zoom, which scales your picture at custom central scaling point (the same way as how digital camera lcd display zooms) and draws it.

```
function precisionScale(img,scale,x,y){
        /** Function precisionScale
         * The function scales the image with a custom central scaling point
         * as opposed to 0,0 (top,left) default central scaling point
         */
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.scale(scale,scale);
        ctx.drawImage(img,-x,-y);
        ctx.scale(-scale,-scale);
        ctx.translate(-x,-y);
    }
```